# "one of several" or "one of the several"

Tags: phrase-usage

[Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+of+several%2Cone+of+the+several&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20several%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20of%20the%20several%3B%2Cc0) shows that "one of several" is used more.

I think we commonly use "the" after "one of". Then why is "the" avoided by the majority of the authors?

Comment: The fact that the use of the article is "common" doesn't mean we always use it. One of several reasons is that it is not needed at all in some cases, like in this sentence.

Comment: You have not  included a sample sentence or two.  The more detailed your question is, the better answers you will likely get. See [Details please!](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please), please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're not avoiding the definite article. It simply requires the proper circumstance to be used.

Consider:

> He chooses Jif® Peanut Butter because he likes the name.

Now consider these continuations of that thought:

> But that is only *one of several* reasons he buys the brand.
>
> He likes the jar's brightly colored label too.
>
> Also *one of the several reasons* for his brand loyalty is the fact that actress Kate Beckinsale and Peter Pan® have hooked up.

Comment: I couldn't understand why you used "_one of several reasons_" without "_the_" in the first case and "_one of the several reasons_" with "_the_" in the second case. Could you explain it please?